# assign Unique value - Using Functions

Tags: oracle, function, aggregate-functions

My Source Table:- First 3 columns are sorted column. The Final OUTPUT has just PLAN and TARGET. This Output table should have unique "TARGET" values assigned to the PLAN.

and the Logic used in Informatica is:- **IIF(PLAN != prev_plan OR prev_target='N',Target, 'Y')** i need to incorporate using Oracle Functions the input parameter should be **PLAN** 
could u please let me know how to derive the below Output. tricky part is  the source table can have different "TARGET" for example refer PLAN='44385'

TABLE:- SOURCE_TABLE

```
PLAN    EFFECTIVE_DATE  POCv                 TARGET
43922   3/26/2012 0:00  VTSSHG                  N
43923   3/26/2012 0:00  FXAFGF                  N
43923   3/26/2012 0:00  VTSSGF                  N
44385   4/17/2013 0:00  RAFGDG                  Y
44385   4/17/2013 0:00  RAFGDG                  N
44385   4/17/2013 0:00  RAFGDG                  N
44386   4/17/2013 0:00  RAFGDG                  Y
```

TABLE:- OUTPUT_TABLE

```
PLAN_ID TARGET
43922   N
43923   N
43923   N
44385   Y
44385   Y
44385   Y
44386   Y
```

Comment: 1. what is the logic for output?, 2.  your source_table's rows are different from the output_table, see :43923.

Comment: Im sorry it is the copy paste error the rows should be identical.im correcting it just we are normalizing/assigning the common value to the "TARGET" column in the OUTPUT table based on the above logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right: Try with this:

see : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04f59/7/0

```
select plan as plan_id, last_value(target) OVER (partition by plan ORDER BY plan) AS target from my_test;
```

You can use this query for an input:

```
select plan_id, effective_date, effective_date, pocv, target 
from
(select plan as plan_id, "EFFECTIVE_DATE" effective_date, "POCv" pocv, last_value(target) OVER (partition by plan ORDER BY plan) AS target from my_test)
where plan_id  = 44385;
```

fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04f59/11/0

Comment: Thanks Ajmal this works. i ahve one question do i need to include effective_date, POCV in the partition by or in Order by clause. because as per the current ETL logic we do do an order by all the columns.

Comment: no, you just need to include the columns in your select and use the effective_date in order by clause

Comment: i can create this as  function rite? Ajmal? passing PLAN as a input parameter ad returning "target".

Comment: Thanks Ajmal implemented this using function-return as i expected. Thanks again :)